# Screw Modifier Texture

Tags: texturing, modifiers

I am trying to use a screw modifier to make a screw that's textured like a basketball, can someone teach me how to do this? I don't understand how one edits texture on a screw modifier material without baking the mesh first, and I can't do that because i intend to animate the parameters on the modifier after texturing.

How do i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To texture a screw modifier without applying and unwrapping, use "Generated" as a texture co-ordinate. If you want more control over it's placement, use a mapping node between the Texture Coordinate and the Image Texture (not shown).

[image: Generated]

Comment: thank you so much!